# Laravel - Delay Job then update to delay further

Tags: laravel, queue, schedule

I have a Laravel project that receives session data via an API.

A client will send data to the API for storage every 30 seconds during a session.

If the client does not send data for say 2 minutes, then I would like to trigger a job to process the session data with the assumption that the session has finished.

My initial thought was to dispatch a queue job with a 2 minute delay every time the data comes in with some sort of reference to the client/session. However, I seems that once I dispatch the job, there is no way of updating the delay again when new data comes in within the 30 seconds.

Is there an easy way to achieve this or does anyone have any other suggestions on how this may be achieved another way?

I hope this is clear.

**EDIT**
To provide an example:
Let's say game players are accumulating points every 30 seconds, their database record gets updated with this score every 30 seconds.

There is no way of knowing that this player has stopped accumulating points, in other words finished the game and can be processed, eg. get's an email notification, etc.

Comment: I'm assuming session data is related to your product rather than browser sessions. You can store information in that particular session to keep track on when was the last session sent. And you can run a scheduled job (minutely) to process session data that has > 2 minutes since last data sent and not processed.

Comment: Thanks @AaronT, correct, session data is related to a product. I considered a scheduled task interval, however, I don't think it is practical querying this very large database table every minute.

Comment: How large is the database? Generally speaking if you have the right indexes it shouldn't be very taxing on the database.

Comment: currently over 1 million rows and growing. It is well indexed but think querying time as you have suggested will result in a slow query.

Comment: you have given me an idea though. I can queue a job with a 2 minute delay and pass in the session id. Then when it handles the dispatch, check the end time < 2 minutes where not processed. My only concern is that if heaps of queues are scheduled every 30 seconds, will this put strain on the server.

Comment: If you want the job to be done in a minimal fashion, I suppose one way to do it is to store a live list of active sessions that are not closed and then remove them from the list once they are processed. You can utilise Cache (redis or what not) to store a key:value pair if performance is a concern. Your scheduled job would only need to interact with the Cache session and query based on id (which should be pretty efficient).

Comment: Perhaps a task that runs every minute and queries the database for any session that was last updated between 2 and 3 minutes previous, then run your function to process the session data?